# DataSet and DataGridView Datasource binding

Tags: datagridview, dataset

I have linked my DataGridView with a DataSet with all the values from one of my database tables. But what i want to do is filter my DataGridView to display certain values from my DataSet:

For example:
`(Where EmployeeID = 4)`,

is there any way of doing this without changing my initial binding object?

```
//Initial datasource
dgv.DataSource = DataSet1.Table[0];

//Some filter code here to display DataSet1 where employeeID = 1
```

//Show these results in the dgv without changing the initial binding.

Comment: I found the answer to this problem

Using a BindingSource Object

BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter and sort using the **DataTable.DefaultView**.

```
DataTable dt = GetProductTable( );
dt.DefaultView.Sort = "ProductName";
dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = "CategoryID=1";
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;
```

Example using the Northwind database:

```
select ProductID, ProductName, SupplierID, CategoryID, UnitPrice from Products;
```