# How to Sort DataGrid or DataSet and bind it in C#

Tags: c#, sorting, datagrid, dataset

I have the text field control and datagrid table on the same form and both linked to a database. Basically the text fields and the table represent the same data from the database. The table is there for a fast navigation and text fields for updating that data. When a user clicks any row on the table, the data from that row populates the text fields and can be modified.

```
//Bind the textbox control to the database table column
TextControl.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", accessDataSet, comboTables.Text + "." + accessDataSet.Tables[comboTables.Text].Columns[i]));

//Finally add the controls to the form
this.Controls.Add(TextControl);
this.Controls.Add(LabelControl);

//arrange controls on the form
arrange_Controls(controlTop, accessDataTable.Columns.Count);

//database view in the grid
dGrid.SetDataBinding(accessDataSet, comboTables.Text);
```

The problem appears after I sort the table. When a row on the sorted table is selected, it does not populate the text fields on the form any more.

```
// Sorting LOGIC. NOTE: I don’t know how to sort my accessDataSet so I do the 
// following
DataView dv = new DataView(accessDataSet.Tables[comboTables.Text]);
dv.Sort = "ID DESC";

// view the grid
dGrid.DataSource = dv;
dGrid.Refresh();
```

I understand that I am sorting DataSource while data binding was performed on DataSet, but I do not know how to sort the DataSet.

How can I sort the table and keep it linked to the TextBoxes? Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of this [link stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9161299/3383479)

Comment: In my case sorting works, but SetDataBinding overwrites it with unsorted data from DataSet. The sorted data is in DataSource, but binding is applied to DataSet.